# Question re misplaced ZRX

Tags: tokens

Perhaps you can help me with an issue related to my previous purchase of ZRX.

On 5/11/20 I purchased 570 ZRX @ $0.35 = $199.5 and stored it on MEW. On 4/30 I purchased 166 for a new total of 736 with a value = $1332; On 5/27 I transferred $1232 worth of ZRX to MetaMask account 0x3238b…b7693 to stake on Ox.org/zrx/account via the Brave browser; then click on Connect to Your Wallet, then click MetaMask to see account and staked balance of $1,226.52 ZRX being staked via MetaMask at acct. # ending in b7693.

On 3/1/23 I tried to access Ox.org via Brave and received the message: “This server could not prove that it is www.ox.org; its security certificate is from dawson.sandelman.ca. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection. Proceed to [www.ox.org](http://www.ox.org) (unsafe). Tried via Samsung mobile device and shows Total ZRX Staked = 42.06.

Tonight I tried to access ox.org/zrx/account via Brave browser and receive the message: "This site can't be reached. ox.org’s DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem. DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE"

I'm confounded.

Today I read your latest news email and thought I'd reply to it and tell you my circumstances to see if you can help me. Please advise.

Comment: I think you want to connect to https://www.0x.org/zrx/account (note the `0` zero in front). In crypto the responsibility to securely manage the funds is in your hands. I'd suggest to pay more attention to the details it is quite easy to lost everything if you don't understand the technology.

Comment: I logged in to my account at that link and it connects me with a MetaMask wallet 0x5facb...ce4c3 with a Zero balance. My ZRX was deposited into my MM wallet 0x3238b…b7693. I don't know why it would direct me to the wallet ce4c3. Can you explain how I can access the wallet ending in b7693? Thank you

Comment: I haven't used 0x in a long time. Try to logout and login again. Make sure the correct address is selected in Metamask.